# How to create overall itinerary

Tags: r

I have a dataset with travels that looks like this

```
from <- c("NYC","PAR", "MAD")
to <- c('PAR', 'SYD', "BCN")
date <- c("05/07","05/07", "06/08")
step <- c(1, 2, 1)
df <- data.frame(from, to, date, step)
```

The "step" column tells the step of the trip.
Some are simple travels (like MAD-BCN), but others have a step (like NYC-PAR-SYD) (or sometimes two steps).

I would like to create a column that resumes the complete trip if there is a step. In our example we should create a column "trip" that contains "NYC-PAR-SYD" for the 2 first rows (NYC-PAR and PAR-SYD), and just "MAD-BCN" for the third row.

The problem for me is that there are hundreds of thousands of rows, and I would like to find an effective way to do it.

Comment: Please provide a better reprex, as it stands it is difficult to understand the structure of your data

Comment: @Onyambu, the link given will not work exactly as desired here as trips are grouped here

Comment: @Onyambu, What if one destination(or origin) is repeated in another trip?

Comment: @AnilGoyal did not think of that. Never mind. I see your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `tidyverse` strategy on an elaborated example

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              from = c("ABC", "BCD", "DEF", "FGH", "CDE", "IJK", "JKL", "LMN"),
                to = c("BCD", "DEF", "FGH", "GHI", "GHI", "JKL", "LMN", "OPQ"),
              step = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)
)

df
#>   from  to step
#> 1  ABC BCD    1
#> 2  BCD DEF    2
#> 3  DEF FGH    3
#> 4  FGH GHI    4
#> 5  CDE GHI    1
#> 6  IJK JKL    1
#> 7  JKL LMN    2
#> 8  LMN OPQ    1

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(step == 1)) %>%
  split(.$id) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
            pivot_longer(c('from', 'to')) %>%
            summarise(id = first(id),
                      itinerary = paste(value[!duplicated(value)], collapse = '->')))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      id itinerary              
#>   <int> <chr>                  
#> 1     1 ABC->BCD->DEF->FGH->GHI
#> 2     2 CDE->GHI               
#> 3     3 IJK->JKL->LMN          
#> 4     4 LMN->OPQ
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It seems to be the best solution here thanks! But how to join it with the rest of the dataset? And do you think it is reproducible in R Base (because I have to integrate it in a tool that doesn't support tidyverse).

Comment: @Awans Glad to have been of help.  In your rest of data, you only have a date column.  If you want to join it with the result, you have to check whether all unique itineraries have same dates.  If yes, that is very easy.  If no, you have to however, decide which dates you'll have to keep.  You may keep all dates too, after concatenation.  But for that you have to give a revised data keeping these things in mind as per actual data.  Moreover, i'll try to work it out on baseR too.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I first thought of a way for a problem with 2 steps but as I noticed there may be more steps involved in your case I decided to generalize my solution. I will post both of them here:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(step == 1)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(from, to), names_to = "dest", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(dup = val == lag(val, default = "Anoush")) %>%
  filter(!dup) %>%
  mutate(across(val, ~ paste(.x, collapse = "-"))) %>%
  select(-dup) %>%
  slice(n = 2:n())

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
  date   step    id dest  val        
  <chr> <dbl> <int> <chr> <chr>      
1 05/07     1     1 to    NYC-PAR-SYD
2 05/07     2     1 to    NYC-PAR-SYD
3 06/08     1     2 to    MAD-BCN 

# With @AnilGoyal's data set

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   id [4]
   step    id dest  val                
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr>              
1     1     1 to    ABC-BCD-DEF-FGH-GHI
2     2     1 to    ABC-BCD-DEF-FGH-GHI
3     3     1 to    ABC-BCD-DEF-FGH-GHI
4     4     1 to    ABC-BCD-DEF-FGH-GHI
5     1     2 to    CDE-GHI            
6     1     3 to    IJK-JKL-LMN        
7     2     3 to    IJK-JKL-LMN        
8     1     4 to    LMN-OPQ
```

My first solution for only two steps which only works for your data set:

```
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(start = ifelse(from == lag(to), lag(from), NA),
         finish = ifelse(to == lead(from), lead(to), NA)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(itn = ifelse(is.na(start), paste(from, to, finish, sep = "-"), 
                      ifelse(is.na(finish), paste(start, from, to, sep = "-"), 
                             paste(from, to, sep = "-")))) %>%
  select(-c(start, finish)) %>%
  mutate(across(itn, ~ str_replace(., "-NA", "")))


# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Rowwise: 
  from  to    date   step itn        
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      
1 NYC   PAR   05/07     1 NYC-PAR-SYD
2 PAR   SYD   05/07     2 NYC-PAR-SYD
3 MAD   BCN   06/08     1 MAD-BCN
```